# Chrome desktop application for web based product

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, google-chrome-app

Chrome desktop application for web based product. Is this possible in chrome web apps

**Product has following items**

1. Angular JS --- Front-end framework
2. Rails --- JSon Communication

I have created the chrome desktop apps, which will directly open the site with icon. It's more feel like desktop application. In any OS it will run. The thing is working fine.

**Problem:**
It will always download the js and css files.

**How i want to develop the chrome desktop apps**

1. When launching the chrome desktop app, save all the assets locally.
2. Whenever chrome desktop app launched, it should refer the locally saved assets (I mean angular js files and css)
3. Before launching the chrome desktop app, it should request the server whether the assets are changed or not. If changed delete the locally saved files and save the latest one.
4. If assets are not changed use the old assets files. In this way, we can avoid the initial loading of all the files from the server.

Anybody did it previously or chrome provide any options for this?

Ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Its totaly possible.

Read these docs: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/offline_apps

By myself i pack the css and javascript into the chrome app so you never have to download them on startup. But in your context its more like a webview app with caching functions.
You can use indexeddb or other local storage APIs to store assets in the client computer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. packaging the css & js on the client side and making the chrome app that's possible. Consider the  following situation 70 users installed the chrome apps and changing the assets in the server side. So we need to update the chrome apps with the latest assets also 70 users have to update the chrome app. I don't want this behavior. The thing i need is, automatically update the client side assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this on the web app side by employing [`ApplicationCache`](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/), which specifically fits what you describe.

> Using the cache interface gives your application three advantages:
>
> - Offline browsing - users can navigate your full site when they're offline
> - Speed - resources come straight from disk, no trip to the network.
> - Resilience - if your site goes down for "maintenance" (as in, someone accidentally breaks everything), your users will get the offline experience
>
> The Application Cache (or AppCache) allows a developer to specify which files the browser should cache and make available to offline users. Your app will load and work correctly, even if the user presses the refresh button while they're offline.

While it is primarily an offline-fallback technique, it allows you to cache resources locally just for speedup purposes. Actually having an offline fallback is a bonus in this case.

---

Actually building a Chrome app for this will probably not help - you cannot update local resources from your web app side, you'll need to update your app through WebStore channels only.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Offline mode works well in chrome app. The thing i needed is, cache and update the asset dynamically.